# How can I block Play Store from installing a specific app

Tags: google-play-store

Is there any option that doesn't allow me to install a specific app from the Play Store ever again on that device? How can I do that?

Comment: if that app has an age limit of 13+ then you can install that app and turn on parental controls in play store..then that app will disappear from your play store..but this will not work for all apps

Comment: I have not tried it but theoretically it should be possible to side-load an app that has the same package name as the PlayStore app. This dummy side-loaded app should then block any installation of the app from Play Store. May be someone known an app generator that creates apps of a very small size and allows to specify the packageName?

Comment: @Robert [Tasker App Factory](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.appfactory) at your service. :-)